# Can SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild be run from within a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm having trouble getting the MSBuild Sonar Runner working within a powershell script.  Sample script is shown below following the documented procedure of executing all steps from the same directory.

```
$sonarRunnerPath = "C:\Users\glenn\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe"
$msbuildPath = "$env:WINDIR\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"

Push-Location $slnDir
& $sonarRunnerPath begin /k:proj:alpha "/n:Project Alpha" /v:1.0.0.%BUILD_NUMBER% /d:sonar.host.url=http://sonar.local
& $msbuildPath /nologo /t:Build /nologo /v:n /clp:ErrorsOnly /m /p:Configuration=Release
& $sonarRunnerPath end
```

However after building (second step) I notice that the $slnDir/.sonarqube/out directory is empty, then after running the end command I receive the standard error message:

```
No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes:
```

Any ideas as to why running msbuild within powershell prevents msbuild from producing ProjectInfo.xml output files?

Comment: Is `%BUILD_NUMBER%` an environment variable? you should be using `$env:BUILD_NUMBER`. If you can you should consider using full paths as supposed to relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild works best with MSBuild version 14. MSBuild 4 is not supported, which is why you are seeing this `No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes:` error. Note that this was mentioned in the few lines under `Possible causes` ;-)

For more details, please refer to the official documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/ahFq

Comment: Wow that was sitting right there staring me in the face, I'm obviously not familiar with standard tool paths for MSBuild.  I have MSBuild 14 installed in my path so I ignored that part of the error message as it was working on the command line.  This also adds the additional improvement of not needing to be in the solution dir when running all 3 commands.  Thanks!